# object is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm having some trouble with Mongodb and Python (Flask).

I have this api.py file, and I want all requests and responses to be in JSON, so I implement as such.

```
#
# Imports
#

from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask
from flask import g
from flask import jsonify
from flask import json
from flask import request
from flask import url_for
from flask import redirect
from flask import render_template
from flask import make_response
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection
from bson import BSON
from bson import json_util

#
# App Create
#

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

#
# Database
#

# connect
connection = Connection()
db = connection['storage']
units = db['storage']


#
# Request Mixins
#

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    #before
    return

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    #after
    return


#
# Functions
#

def isInt(n):
    try:
        num = int(n)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def isFloat(n):
    try:
        num = float(n)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def jd(obj):
    return json.dumps(obj, default=json_util.default)

def jl(obj):
    return json.loads(obj, object_hook=json_util.object_hook)

#
# Response
#

def response(data={}, code=200):
    resp = {
        "code" : code,
        "data" : data
    }
    response = make_response(jd(resp))
    response.headers['Status Code'] = resp['code']
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
    return response


#
# REST API calls
#

# index
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return response()

# search
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search(): 
    return response()

# add
@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    unit = request.json
    _id = units.save(unit)
    return response(_id)

# get
@app.route('/show', methods=['GET'])
def show():
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
    return response(db.units.find())

#
# Error handing
#

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return response({},404)


#
# Run it!
#

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

The problem here is json encoding data coming to and from mongo. It seems I've been able to "hack" the add route by passing the request.json as the dictionary for save, so thats good... the problem is /show. This code does not work... When I do some logging I get

```
TypeError: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x109bda150> is not JSON serializable
```

Any ideas? I also welcome any suggestions on the rest of the code, but the JSON is killing me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just want to add the error that led me here to this question and solution: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you pass `db.units.find()` to `response` you pass a [`pymongo.cursor.Cursor`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) object to `json.dumps` ... and `json.dumps` doesn't know how to serialize it to JSON.  Try getting the actual objects by iterating over the cursor to get its results:

```
[doc for doc in db.units.find()]
```

Comment: @YisraelDov - do you have the same setup as the OP?  Note that he is using `json.dumps(obj, default=json_util.default)`, not just `json.dumps(obj)`.

Comment: when I do `db.units.find()[:]` It always returns me a cursor object. I ended up just looping through and adding to an array, and then it worked.

Comment: Yep, it looks like the API has changed ... I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 37):

While @ErenGüven shows you a nice manual approach to solving this json serializing issue, pymongo comes with a [utility to accomplish this for you](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.4/api/pymongo/json_util.html). I use this in my own django mongodb project:

```
import json
from bson import json_util

json_docs = []
for doc in cursor:
    json_doc = json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default)
    json_docs.append(json_doc)
```

Or simply:

```
json_docs = [json.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default) for doc in cursor]
```

And to get them back from json again:

```
docs = [json.loads(j_doc, object_hook=json_util.object_hook) for j_doc in json_docs]
```

The helper utilities tell `json` how to handle the custom mongodb objects.

Comment: you can see I'm using this too, my problem was forgetting to iterate through the cursor! Thanks though :)

Comment: `from pymongo import json_util` has been deprecated. Use `from bson import json_util` instead.

Answer (score 16):

```
import json
from bson import json_util

docs_list  = list(db.units.find())
return json.dumps(docs_list, default=json_util.default)
```

Answer (score 4):

To encode MongoDB documents to JSON, I use a similar approach to the one below which covers `bson.objectid.ObjectId` and `datetime.datetime` types.

```
class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """A C{json.JSONEncoder} subclass to encode documents that have fields of
    type C{bson.objectid.ObjectId}, C{datetime.datetime}
    """
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, bson.objectid.ObjectId):
            return str(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

enc = CustomEncoder()
enc.encode(doc)
```

As for the Cursor, you need to iterate it and get documents first.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Its a cursor object. Iterate over it , and you get python dicts. Again to serialise do this:

```
import json 
from bson import json_util
```

let's say this is my query:

```
details = mongo.db.details.find()
# this is cursor object

#iterate over to get a list of dicts
details_dicts = [doc for doc in details]

#serialize to json string
details_json_string = json.dumps(details_dicts,default=json_util.default)
```

If u wish to return the above , it will be just a string. Do this to return it as usable dict or json

```
return json.loads(details_json_string)
#return jsonified version rather than string without  unwanted "\" in earlier json string!
```

Hope that helps! Happy Coding!

Yea plain old `jsonify` works, if your query doesn't contain some complex filed like Objectid , etc!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are looking for a more plain python way of sending the response then create an empty list and append the values inside it and finally return this list in JSON format.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

@app.route('/view', methods=["GET'])
def viewFun():
   data = units.find()
   s = []
   for i in data:
      s.append(str(i))
   return jsonify(s)
```

May be not the perfect one but it works!

Answer (score 0):

if the document id is of no use, you can simply exclude it by

```
objects = collection.find({}, {'_id': False})
```

after that simply convert it to list of dictionaries by

```
list(objects)
```